# How to use image in android:src="" from assets folder instead of drawable

Tags: android

**As we use image from drawable in src**

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage"/>
```

**Can we use here from assets folder?**

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="myImage.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible directly in XML although you can do it pragmatically.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
try {
    InputStream ims = assetManager.open("my_image.jpg");
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
} catch (IOException ex) {
   return;
}
```